# How to save a multi dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a form where each row of the form has four values: id, category name, notes and status. However the form has many rows. When I update the form, I need to be able to save each row in the DB as a row of data like this:

```
cat_id = 42, cat_name= cedar, notes = notes for cedar, status = active.
```

My problem is that the `$_POST` array is not organised in this way:

```
Array ( 
  [_token] => GJG5lP2bz08OPeEAfn7DKigFWgxkB1ZxdEssVYgO 
  [cat_id] => Array ( [42] => 42 [22] => 22 [1] => 1 [31] => 31 ) 
  [cat_name] => Array ( [42] => cedar [22] => Materials [1] => Product
  [31] => Slates ) 
  [notes] => Array ( [42] => notes here [22] => Notes here materials [1] 
  => Notes here products [31] => Notes here slates ) 
  [status] => Array ( [42] => active [22] => active [1] => active [31] 
  => active )
 )
```

I need help in how to get this arranged so it can be saved with sql,

Using Laravel, but I expect that is in this case irrelevant unless somehow I can get it into a usable collection.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Is this what your looking for?

```
 <form action="multiarray.php" method="post">
      <input type="text" name="item['token']">
      <input type="text" name="item['cat_id'][0]">
      <input type="text" name="item['cat_name'][0]">
      <input type="text" name="item['notes'][0]">
      <input type="text" name="item['status'][0]">
      <input type="submit" value="submit">  
    </form>

    <?php

        if(!empty($_POST)){

            $array = $_POST;        
            print_r($array);

        }

    ?>
```

Output:

> Array ( [item] => Array ( ['token'] => x ) ['cat_id']
>   => Array ( [0] => x ) ['cat_name'] => Array ( [0] => x ) ['notes'] => Array ( [0] => x ) ['status'] => Array ( [0] => x ) ) )

Comment: I changed my html to your recommendation, however the resulting array is identical.
array:2 [▼
  "_token" => "GJG5lP2bz08OPeEAfn7DKigFWgxkB1ZxdEssVYgO"
  "item" => array:4 [▼
    "cat_id" => array:4 [▼
      42 => "42"
      22 => "22"
      1 => "1"
      31 => "31"
    ]
    "'cat_name'" => array:4 [▼
      42 => "cedar"
      22 => "Materials"
      1 => "Product"
      31 => "Slates"
    ]
    "'notes'" => array:4 [▶]
    "'status'" => array:4 [▶]
  ]
]